# Any Function in Ruby determine the difference between folders level?

Tags: ruby, file-io, file

What I'm trying to do is to figure out if some folders is one of children / parents Or not related.

Is there any function in the **Ruby File API**? if not how to figure it out?

For example:

```
real_path_1 = "/Users/amr/Code/xx/zz"
real_path_2 = "/Users/amr/Code/"
# when I have to compare between these paths like:
f_level(real_path_1, real_path_2)
# it should return +2
# that means real_path_1 is **parent** of real_path_2
# with 2 levels depth
```

Also another example:

```
real_path_1 = "/Users/amr/Code/"
real_path_2 = "/Users/amr/Code/foo/bar/inside"
# when I have to compare between these paths like:
f_level(real_path_1, real_path_2)
# it should return -3
# that means real_path_1 is **child** of real_path_2
# with 3 levels depth
```

Another example:

```
real_path_1 = "/Users/amr/Code/"
real_path_2 = "/Users/amr/Code/"
# when I have to compare between these paths like:
f_level(real_path_1, real_path_2)
# it should return 0
# that means real_path_1 is **same level** as real_path_2
```

When returns *nil*:

```
real_path_1 = "/Users/other/Code/" # or "/folder2/"
real_path_2 = "/Users/amr/Code/" # or "/folder1/"
# when I have to compare between these paths like:
f_level(real_path_1, real_path_2)
# it should return nil
# that means real_path_1 is **not at same level** as real_path_2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def f_level a,b
    if a[/^#{b}/] && (b[-1,1] == '/' || $'[0,1] == '/')
        $'.scan(/[^\/]+/).size
    elsif b[/^#{a}/] && (a[-1,1] == '/' || $'[0,1] == '/')
        -($'.scan(/[^\/]+/).size)
    end
end

"/Users/amr/Code/xx/zz"
"/Users/amr/Code/"
2
"/Users/amr/Code/"
"/Users/amr/Code/xx/zz"
-2
"/Users/amr/Code/"
"/Users/amr/Code/"
0
"/Users/other/Code/"
"/Users/amr/Code/"
nil
```

Comment: it doesnt represent the expected outputs! it gives 'nil'

Comment: this puts f_level("/Users/amr/Code/xx/zz", "/Users/amr/Code/") should return 2! it returns nil!

Comment: @amrnt: language developers must be very careful about the features they include in order not to clutter the libraries. IMO it's understandable this is not part of the stdlib.

Answer (score 3):

Another idea without regular expressions:

```
def f_level(path1_string, path2_string)
  path1, path2 = [path1_string, path2_string].map { |s| s.split(File::SEPARATOR) }  
  minsize = [path1, path2].map(&:size).min
  path1.first(minsize) == path2.first(minsize) ? path1.size - path2.size : nil
end

raise unless f_level("/Users/amr/Code/xx/zz",  "/Users/amr/Code/") == 2
raise unless f_level( "/Users/amr/Code/", "/Users/amr/Code/foo/bar/inside") == -3
raise unless f_level("/Users/amr/Code/", "/Users/amr/Code/") == 0 
raise unless f_level("/Users/other/Code/", "/Users/amr/Code/") == nil
```

Comment: I like this solution, however I think the regular expression one is far efficient when it comes to array vs string comparison, but it's still a good one. Good job!

Comment: I like your `split` better than my `scan`.